# How to test Routing/Navigation in Angular with Jest/Spectator?

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-routing, angular-spectator

I'm trying to write end-to-end specs for an Angular 10 app and I can't manage to test going from a component to another via the router/navigation (working fine when I run the app in a browser).

My route is configured like:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'bulk-edit',
    component: BulkEditComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Bulk Edit',
    },
  }
];
```

I have my nav bar template as:

```html
<header>
  <mat-toolbar fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" color="primary">
    <div>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="auth.login()" *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn">
        <mat-icon>login</mat-icon>
      </button>

      <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
        <mat-icon>apps</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item routerLink="bulk-edit" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn">
          <mat-icon>settings_input_component</mat-icon>
          <span>Bulk Edit</span>
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
      <span>{{ title }}</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <app-publisher-selector *ngIf="auth.loggedIn"></app-publisher-selector>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="auth.logout()" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn" matTooltip="Log Out">
        <mat-icon>sensor_door</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>
</header>
```

And my spec goes like:

```js
spectator = createComponent();
loader    = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(spectator.fixture);

const menu = await loader.getHarness(MatMenuHarness);
await menu.open();

const menuItems = await menu.getItems();
expect(menuItems.length).toEqual(1);
expect(await menuItems[0].getText()).toMatch('Bulk Edit');

await menuItems[0].click();
await spectator.fixture.whenStable();

// THIS IS WHERE IT STOPS PASSING
expect(spectator.inject(Location).path()).toEqual('bulk-edit');
```

I've tried different variants for `createComponent`, either `createComponentFactory` or `createRoutingFactory`, with or without `stubsEnabled`. Nothing seems to be working and the routing doesn't trigger loading the component attached to the route.

I've been able to add an event on the click that console.log, and the click does trigger it during spec execution, so the event propagates; just the routing doesn't run.

The value of `(spectator.fixture.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement).outerHTML` does not change.

Edit: I've created a small reproduction project, it's hosted on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-epvfki however it does not run directly on StackBlitz (could not have jest running in the browser), so it requires being dowloaded and

```
yarn install
ng test
```

This test app has 2 buttons leading to 2 routes, the spec clicks on a button and test that the routing triggered, and it does not.

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo or something similar?

Comment: I've tried but I can't manage to get jest running on stackblitz while trimming down my project into a more scoped reproduction environment. I was hoping either someone can point out something that's obviously wrong in my snippets, or give me some pointers for what to double check in my app.

Comment: @AndreiGătej I've created a smaller scope project and hosted it on StackBlitz, I updated my initial post with instructions to reproduce the problem. Thanks